# how to make a java program to autoexecute by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java program which has to be running in the background when eclipse is launched and cleanup program when eclipse exits.

I mean is there anything like `eclipse_startup()` where i can put my class which has to be executed and runs in background as demon .  `eclipse_cleanup()` to terminate the demon.

Comment: write a batch-file? tweak .bashrc? depends on your Os

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Eclipse plugin and launch it on start up using this [extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_startup.html). Since it is a plugin, it should shut down together with Eclipse automatically.

However, this approach is deprecated and [discouraged in the FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Can_I_activate_my_plug-in_when_the_workbench_starts?). Still, it would probably work if you only need this for yourself.